# C++11 lambda function - how to pass parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

I used lambda function to pass it to `std::condition_variable` wait() function, but that is not the case. I use lambda functions that don't receive any parameters, and everything is absolutely clear for me. But I totally don't understand how is used lamdba function that have parameters list. Show lambda with parameters are used? How to pass parameters to them?

Comment: Any resource you find on lambdas will explain how to make them take parameters.

Comment: @chris I know hpw to make then take parameters - [](int parameter) {lambda body},  but show will I use this lambda?

Comment: Just like a function.

Comment: @chris I was confused that lamdba has no name, answers below helped me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Show lambda with parameters are used? How to pass parameters to them?

It works exactly like with any other type of callable object:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto l = [] (int i) { std::cout << "The answer is " << i; };
    l(42);
}
```

Also notice, that you do not need to store a lambda in a variable in order to invoke it. The following is an alternative way to rewrite the above program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    [] (int i) { std::cout << "The answer is " << i; } (42);
    //                                                 ^^^^
    //                                 Invoked immediately!
}
```

The type of a lambda function (the so-called "lambda closure") is defined by the compiler, and is a functor with a call operator whose signature is the one you specify when defining the lambda. Therefore, you call a lambda exactly as you would call a functor (i.e. exactly as you would call a function - or any callable object).

Thus, if you want to assign a lambda to an object, the best practice is to let the compiler deduce its type by using `auto`. If you do not want or cannot use `auto`, then you may:

1. Use function pointers for non-capturing lambdas (capturing lambdas are *not* convertible to function pointers). In the above case, thus, the following will also work:

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   int main()
   {
       void (*f)(int) = [] (int i) { std::cout << "The answer is " << i; };
       f(42);
   }
   ```
2. Use `std::function` (this is always possible, even if the lambda is capturing):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <functional>

   int main()
   {
       std::function<void(int)> f = [] (int i) 
                                  { std::cout << "The answer is " << i; };
       f(42);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

```
auto lambda = [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; };
assert(lambda(1, 2) == 3);
```

Comment: ahha! and here auto hides int(*p)(int, int)?

Comment: @Littlebitter the type of lambdas is implementation-defined, hence you need `auto`. You can convert some lambdas (those that don't capture anything) to function pointers, but that's not their actual type (similar to how you can convert an `int` to a `long`, but an `int` is not a `long`).

Comment: and if lambda will be [] (int a, int b) -> int { return a + b; }; it will be possible to create pointer to function variable with type I described, without auto?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all lambdas are storable in `std::function`, aren't they? And @Littlebitter, Assigning that to the type in your first comment will work because it doesn't capture anything.

Comment: Yes, you can do `int (*lambda)(int, int) = [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; }`, since the lambda doesn't capture any variables.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a variable to hold your lambda -- you can call it directly:

```
std::cout << [](int n) { return n + 1 ; } (99) << std::endl ;
```